# How to plot numeric vectors over time into a graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe that looks something like this where each row represents a person and the columns represent some values at different timepoints. I'm trying to plot them into a graph (ggplot preferred) where the x-axis would be the 3 months, 6 months, 9 months while the y-axis would show the mean +/- SD (with NA removed) for the whole column then stratified by the `df$type`.

```
   3months 6months 9months  type
1       1      NA       4 young
2       2       3       4 young
3       3       3      NA   old
4      NA       3       4   old
5       5       3       4   old
```

Is there any way to achieve this or do I have to manually compute all the means and SDs and then put them into a more traditional dataframe before plotting it out? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jeff. The sample data you have included would not allow the plot you described, since the standard deviation is either zero or not defined for most of the subgroups. Could you share a more realistic data set?

Comment: Ahh sorry I can't put the real data public so I opted for a simplified version, but the dataset has thousands of data points (with NAs interspersed) so it should have a proper SD. I was mainly wondering was it possible to have a whole column as input with the colnames() as the x-axis points?

Comment: I can make up some data to show you an answer if you like?

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a more realistically sized sample with 100 rows:

```r
set.seed(69)
nrows <- 100
df <- data.frame(`3months` = c(sample(c(1:5, NA), nrows/2, TRUE),
                               sample(c(3:7, NA), nrows/2, TRUE)),
                  `6months` = c(sample(c(2:6, NA), nrows/2, TRUE),
                                sample(c(4:8, NA), nrows/2, TRUE)),
                  `9months` = c(sample(c(3:7, NA), nrows/2, TRUE),
                                sample(c(5:9, NA), nrows/2, TRUE)),
                  type = rep(c("young", "old"), each = nrows/2))
names(df) <- c("3months", "6months", "9months", "type")
```

The first six rows look like this:

```
head(df)
#>   3months 6months 9months  type
#> 1       1       2       6 young
#> 2       3      NA       5 young
#> 3       2       6      NA young
#> 4       5      NA       7 young
#> 5      NA       6      NA young
#> 6       5       4       6 young
```

If we want to have 3months, 6months, 9months on the x axis, we need to pivot our data into long format to give a single column where each of these are factor levels. We can achieve this with `tidyr::pivot_longer`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

pivot_longer(df, 1:3) %>%
  group_by(type, name) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE),
            upper = mean + sd(value, na.rm = TRUE),
            lower = mean - sd(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, mean, group = type, color = type)) +
  geom_line(position = position_dodge(width = 0.1)) +
  geom_point(col = "black",
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.1)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), 
                width = 0.2, alpha = 0.5,
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.1)) +
  labs(x = "Time", y = "Mean +/- SD")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this works very well! As I understand it, is ```pivot_longer()``` the newer version of ```gather()``` which is most useful when I want to transform my column names into a variable that is incorporated into a dataframe in a tidy format?